# Shared pointer to array in pool-allocated memory

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, allocator

I am working on writing a fixed-capacity, copy-on-write "string" class which is capable of using Allocators for its memory allocations.  Eventually, I want to be able to have these "strings" use a memory pool which returns fixed-sized chunks of memory.  If the "capacity" of the string being created is less than the pool chunk size, the extra memory is "wasted." If the capacity is larger, this is an assert failure (i.e., you cannot create a string that is larger than the pool chunk size).

To implement the copy-on-write behavior, I am trying to figure out how to use this pool to create shared pointers to arrays within this chunk of memory.  I can't just use std::shared_ptr(pool.allocate(...)) because I need both the control block AND memory to be allocated in the SAME chunk of memory allocated by the pool.

Visually, the memory should look like:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|              Memory Pool Chunk                   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| Control Block | Array of characters ... | UNUSED |
----------------------------------------------------
```

From my research, I can see that this is example what std::make_shared does; it allocates both the control block and object in a contiguous chunk of memory.  However, it also looks like you can't allocate an arbitrarily-sized array using std::make_shared.  You can use it to allocate std::array objects, but you of course need to know the size at compile time, whereas the size of the array I want to allocate is known at run-time.

My next thought was to simply implement my own, stripped down shared pointer.  Since I don't need weak pointers or custom deleters, this seems like I should just be able to store an allocator and reference count in some sort of "header" in the memory I get back from the pool.  Then, the rest of the memory can be used for the array.

However, I cannot figure out how you are supposed to store an allocate within a header and later use the allocator to, for example, make a deep copy of the data.

Could someone help either:

a) Direct me towards a way of doing this using the already build-in standard library constructs OR

b) Help me figure out how to implement my own shared pointer that meets the requirements above

Comment: Why bother with trying to allocate (sub-allocate) a variable sized block?  If your string  has to be in a single block then always allocate the whole block to the Control-block+string-data.  So your string struct is always fixed size.

Comment: @RichardCritten The reason, unless I am mistaken, is that this should work for ALL allocators.  So, for example, if I use the normal heap instead of my pool, there is no limit to the string size.  However, if I use the pool, now there is a limit.

Comment: That's precisely what [std::allocate_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) is for.

Comment: I find your design... confusing. The entire point of a pool allocator is that allocation is supposed to be extremely cheap. The whole point of a copy-on-write string is to avoid expensive allocations. So you're trying to use a technique designed to avoid an expensive operation with a version of that operation which is very cheap. That's quite a disconnect.

Comment: @Frank Correct me if I'm wrong, but looking at the standard, it looks like this only works with arrays in C++20. I can only use up to C++17.

Comment: @NicolBolas However, I believe that "cheap" is a relative term.  I have an embedded system which has limited memory, thus, even though a memory pool allocation is cheap, I can't make many copies.  However, there may be multiple users of a particular string, thus the need for a shared pointer.  In addition, if I pass strings across threads, I only want to pass a (shared) pointer, not a whole copy of the string.

Comment: @PatrickWright You want to allocate statically-sized blocks, so it's not actually an array allocation in the first place.

Comment: @PatrickWright: "*I can't make many copies.*" But you've made every slot in your string pool *bigger* by having to stick a shared pointer control block in it. And those are *not small*, at least relative to SSO string sizes. A control block consists of two integers plus a copy of your allocator object plus a pointer to the object it manages. That's 16-24 bytes. If your string size limit was 32 (a reasonable limit for many uses where a maximum string length makes sense), then you could easily get 50%+ more slot capacity just by doing more copies.

Comment: If using boost is an option: [`boost::make_shared` & `boost::allocate_shared`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#make_shared) allow dynamic array sizes with c++17. You might also want to take a look at [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr). intrusive_ptr's have no control block at all, and leave the reference-counting to the contained object. due to this intrusive_ptrs are smaller than shared_ptrs (they just wrap the bare pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid trying to use `shared_ptr` for this. Not just because you need C++20 in order for `allocate_shared` to work on arrays, but also because it is inefficient for your embedded needs.

The `shared_ptr` control block has two reference counts in order to allow for weak pointers. Your particular use case doesn't need weak pointers, so you only need one count. The control block has a pointer to the object it manages. In your use case, the array is always right after the control block. The control block has a copy of the allocator, but your string class already has that, so it doesn't need it in the control block. And so on.

You should use a hand-rolled solution so that you can minimize the amount of book-keeping memory, thus maximizing the amount of actual string storage you get.